# Android WebView PHP Disable Zoom On User Inputs

Tags: php, android

I would like to disable the zoom functionality on the a `phpbb` forum form which I am showing in my `WebView` whenever a user clicks on the username and password fields on a mobile Android phone.

It is advised to use

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=max-device-width, user-scalable=no">
```

but I use PHP not HTML. Which PHP file do I need to edit and which code do I need to use to accomplish the same results as with the HTML code mentioned above?

Answer (score 0):

After fiddling with SciTE and css, I edited the forum theme "form.css" and edited the section on inputbox:focus with 16px as this is the default zoom level value used by Android and iPhone. The WebView no longer zooms in on input field. hope this will help others as well.

```
.inputbox:hover, .inputbox:focus {
border: 1px solid transparent;
font-size: 16px;
outline-style: none;
```